# What WinForm Control Do I Want?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

This is probably the weakest, least technical question that stackoverflow has ever embraced. I want to use the control shown - the straight line that splits the buttons in the following image:

[image: Unknown Control]

What is this control called? Any help here would be appreciated because I cannot find out what exactly I want!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you create your own control and use the graphics classes to draw the line, a lot of people just use a label with a fixed height and border:

[Draw horizontal divider in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296110/draw-horizontal-divider-in-winforms)

Comment: I thought it was a set control - I did not think for one moment it was a type of 'fudge'! Thanks very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this in the toolbox under the name 'LineShape', just drag and drop this onto your form! I have this in my toolbox under 'Visual Basic PowerPacks' so you may have to get hold of a DLL somewhere and reference this in your project. Hope this helps

Comment: I think this is available by default only in VB.Net.

Comment: I use it in c# as well as VB so i'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

There is a LineShape control included in [Visual Basic Power Pack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/07/24/visual-basic-power-packs-is-included-in-visual-studio-2008-sp1.aspx).

But honestly, I would create my own control (see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3087442/870604)): really easy to do and avoids to add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.VS.dll` for such a simple line control.